# Securing a Linux SFTP in an ACI. IPTables? Vnet?

Tags: azure, network-programming, azure-rm-template, azure-container-instances

I setup a simple SFTP using ACI following this great tutorial: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/resources/samples/sftp-creation-template/

Problem is this thing has a public IP, and no semblance of a firewall to secure it.  i would like to make this thing more secure.  I am pretty good w/ Azure VNets but dont have a lot of expeirence w/ Linux or ACIs yet.  the way i see it i can do one of two things

1) deploy this ACI within my vnet and control access via a NSG or similar.  Not sure if this will work with an ACI? Is there any limitations to this?

2) use IPtables in the linux build?  the sftp build is based on atmoz/sftp but its configured as a ARM deployment template.  I really only need to restrict access to this SFTP to a single IP, so i could make two rules but if i go this route i'd love to have it configured in the ARM template itself.

so my questions are really
a) what is the best practice here?  The vnet seems more secure logically
b) for my own edification, where would i go learn how to configure something like IPTables in a ARM Template? is that something that can be configured in a deployment template?

thanks all,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, both options should work with ACI. But I'd prefer to select NSG as it's easier to manage it on the Azure portal instead of accessing the instance. Also, it would control network access in a subnet, it does little impact on your instance settings. IPTables works inside the instance If your Image supports IPTables.

There are some limitations when you deploy ACI with VNet. Such as

- To deploy container groups to a subnet, the subnet cannot contain any other resource types.
- This feature is in preview and available with some regions.
- Container groups deployed to a virtual network don't currently support exposing containers directly to the internet with a public IP address or a fully qualified domain name. So you may need to add a service like [Azure Application gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/overview) reverse proxy to direct your public-facing traffic to your backend instance.
- Outbound security rules in NSGs applied to a subnet delegated to Azure Container Instances aren't currently enforced

For more details, you could read this: [Deploy container instances into an Azure virtual network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-vnet#unsupported-networking-scenarios).

Comment: Thanks for this, i agree with this approach however budgetary concerns do come into consideration w/ Azure App gateways (they are so expensive!) but i do get that we need something as the reverse proxy.  Thank you for your information i've reviewed that document about deploying ACIs into VNets and will give it a go.